# Unable to find a way to store data into an array inside a class module

Tags: excel, vba

I've been wrestling with this problem for a while. My problem is that I have a bunch of JSON data and I want to represent it as objects.

Arrays are problematic.

I create a class module such as `FancyCat` with a `public Name as String` for its name.

Then I can set this with

```
Dim MyFancyCat as FancyCat
Set MyFancyCat = new FancyCat

FancyCat.Name = JSONData("Name")
```

I've typed that from memory but I think it's correct. Anyhoo, it works fine.

The problem is that a fancy cat has several pairs of socks. The number of socks is variable.

In vba you cannot for some reason have a public array. So this code is illegal:

`public Socks() as FancySock 'Illegal`

Looking on SO I found two solutions, one, to make it private and use a property to access it, and the other, to declare it as Variant and then stick an array into it later.

My approach to populating this array, is to examine the JSON array to get the `Count`, and then to `ReDim` the array to match and then populate it.

The problem is my `ReDim` statement refuses to work.

It seems I cannot redim a property, I get an error. And I also get an error trying to redim the public variant field. My ReDim works OK if I declare a local array and redim it, so potentially I could do that and then assign it to the property... but it just seems bizarre that I can't redim it directly.

Any idea why it's not working?

With the Variant approach above my code is:

`ReDim MyFancyCat.Socks(socksLength) As FancySocks`

And in the FancyCat class module:

`public Socks As Variant`

I get `Method or Data Member Not Found`.

The error for the other approach was different but I rejigged all my code to try the second approach so I am not sure what it was.

---

Edit: I'm gonna explain what I am trying to do a bit more clearly. I have some JSON data coming in, and I want to store it as an object hierarchy.

In C# I would do this (pseudo code without linq shortcuts):

```
var myData = ReadJsonData(); // Produces a kind of dictionary

var myFancyCat = new FancyCat();

myFancyCat.Name = myData["Name"];
myFancyCat.Age = myData["Age"];
myFancyCat.Socks = new List<FancySock>();

foreach (var sock in myData["Socks"])
{
    myFancyCat.Socks.Add(sock);
}
```

In excel I want to do the same thing.

So I make a class module for `FancyCat` and `FancySock` and give `FancyCat` public members for Name, Age etc but then I also want an array of socks that my cat owns. I wanted to do this with strongly typed references, e.g. my c# code above I can do:

`myFancyCat.Socks[0].Colour // Intellisense works, shows colour as a property`

However it seems in excel you can't have publicly declared arrays. So you can get around this according to the comments by declaring it as `variant` and then sticking an array in anyway, but you would lose the intellisense. Or you can use a get/let property which kinda works but is more fiddly as it seems you can't actually expose an array using a get/let you have to have it take an index and expose elements individually.

So at this point I am thinking forget the strongly typed it's not happening, perhaps use a collection?

The `FancySock` class may have further nested arrays within it. I've read that there's no `ByRef` for arrays (at least, not completely - I think you can get an array ByRef but not set one?). I am not sure if that would create problems with trying to set it.

But ultimately, I just want to end up with my JSON data represented easily in an OO way, so that in my excel ultimately I can just do

`myFancyCat.Name` or `myFancyCat.Socks.Count` or `myFancyCat.Socks(1).Colour` etc

It seems much harder than it looks to simply deserialise JSON into 'objects' in vba.

Comment: Just use a [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object) instead of an array.

Comment: I considered that, but I read that collections are somewhat slower and don't have a type. I hoped to preserve intellisense by using an Array. Plus, I am copying a specific sized array of data from json into the array so having dynamic sizing is not required. However given the difficulties perhaps that is the best approach.

Comment: Use a public sub in your class to handle the assignment and resizing rather than a Property Let. Have a Property Get to retrieve it.

Comment: You can try declaring `Socks As Variant` (without parenthesis). Then you can simply place an array as `Socks = myArray`... No `Dim`, `ReDim` necessary. Even if you place a second time an array with different dimensions.

Comment: VBA is flexible from this point of view when declare the variable as `Variant`. Or simple `Dim Socks`. `Variant` is implicit.

Comment: The `Variant` method requires me to create the array locally and then set it, what I wanted to do was skip needing a local array. However I suppose it's not possible.

Comment: Why not being possible? I have to leave my office now, but you can give to the array values as to a string, if use `Let fillMyArray(arr as variant)` and then `clsArr = arr`, where `clsArr` was declared as I suggested above...

Comment: Ah, it is the variant part that threw me. After much pain I found you can't have property get/let for arrays which is what I was trying to do, but Variant would bypass that I suppose. VBA is very restricting as I was hoping to have my array strongly typed but it seems to be impossible. If I am going the Variant and losing strongly typed, perhaps I should just use a Collection instead.

Comment: What do you want meaning by saying "losing strongly typed"? Doesn't the class I posted help you to solve your problem?

Comment: If the member is a concrete type you get intellisense, but if it is variant you don't, basically. But since it seems you can't have public arrays it is moot, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

1. Insert a class module, name it `FancyCat` and copy the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Private arrL As Object
Public myName As String, myAge As Long

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set arrL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
End Sub
Public Property Let Name(strName As String)
   myName = strName
End Property
Public Property Let Age(lngAge As String)
   myAge = lngAge
End Property
Public Property Let SocksAdd(sMember)
   arrL.Add sMember
End Property

Public Property Get Socks() As Variant
   Socks = arrL.toarray()
End Property
```

2. Use it in the next testing `Sub`:

```
Sub testClassDictListArray()
  Dim myFancyCat As New FancyCat, myData As Object
  Dim arrSocks, sock
  
  Set myData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")           'this should be the dictionary returned by ParseJSON
  myData.Add "Name", "John Doe": myData.Add "Age", 35
  myData.Add "Socks", Array("Blue", "White", "Red", "Green", "Yellow")
  
  myFancyCat.Name = myData("Name")
  myFancyCat.Age = myData("Age")
  For Each sock In myData("Socks")
        myFancyCat.SocksAdd = sock
  Next sock
  
  arrSocks = myFancyCat.Socks
  Debug.Print Join(arrSocks, "|")
End Sub
```

I am not sure I perfectly understand the scenario you try putting in discussion...

If you want to benefit of instellisense suggestions, I will tell you what references to be added. Even, I will send two pieces of code to automatically add the necessary references (I mean, `Scripting.Dictionary` and ArrayList`).

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: I think this will work, I was hoping to avoid using variant but I suppose there isn't much choice. I think excel doesn't do references with arrays even using byref though so a collection might be better but I honestly can't find definitive explanations of why to use one over the other...

Comment: @NibblyPig Shouldn't it be better to explain what you want accomplishing? We maybe can better suggest a solution if we know what your goal is...

Comment: I have updated my question to explain. I just want to load json into class modules basically.

Comment: @NibblyPig Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In your class:

```
Private m_Name As String
Private m_Socks() As String

Public Property Let Name(Name As String)
    m_Name = Name
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_Name
End Property

Public Sub SetSize(Quantity As Long)
    ReDim m_Socks(1 To Quantity)
End Sub

Public Property Let Socks(Index As Long, Sock As String)
        m_Socks(Index) = Sock
End Property

Public Property Get Socks(Index As Long) As String
    Socks = m_Socks(Index)
End Property
```

In a regular module:

```
Sub UseFancyCat()

    Dim MyFancyCat As FancyCat
    Set MyFancyCat = New FancyCat
    
    MyFancyCat.Name = "Fancy Name"
    MyFancyCat.SetSize 2
    MyFancyCat.Socks(1) = "Sock1"
    MyFancyCat.Socks(2) = "Sock2"
    
    Debug.Print MyFancyCat.Name
    Debug.Print MyFancyCat.Socks(1)
    Debug.Print MyFancyCat.Socks(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That is such a lot of code, I was hoping to just do a simple redim but if that's the only way, so be it. I am curious to know why ReDim didn't work though, perhaps it only works on local variables or something.

Comment: I am getting a compile error, `Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray or an invalid Set final parameter`. The only difference in my code is that I am not using a String, I am using a class module. Your example uses Socks as a string but Socks is an object not a string?